TikZ or Parser Having Memory of a Previous Diagram?
This is a follow-up to this extremely thorough answer by @StevenB.Segletes, in which he completed an SGF Parser saga I had been working on (SGFs are the text files for the board game of Go). Apparently, though, there's a bug, and I believe it's about either TikZ, or somewhere else in his code, having a memory of what the color on a certain coordinate changed to in a previous diagram.

The code in this question is from this project.

For example, if I draw a diagram from scratch, there's no problem:


However, once I play a Black move on a position that's going to get used by future diagrams (in this case, 2-2), we start having a problem:



Since I'm just flipping the colors in order to get the right contrast, we don't get the "A" label anymore, and the border/fill of the triangles also get flipped.
Maybe if I could force everything to be white after the drawing of a diagram, that could be a workaround.
I suspect this is due to how @StevenB.Segletes' is identifying the colors. I think he is doing so with:
\newcommand\StoneColor[1]{% COMPLEMENTARY COLOR OF REFERENCED STONE
  \ifcsname thecolorat#1\endcsname
    \csname thecolorat#1\endcsname
  \else
    white% COMPLEMENT OF DEFAULT LABEL COLOR WHEN NOT ATOP EXISTING STONE
  \fi
}

% ...

\newcommand{\drawMoveFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \expandafter\xdef\csname thecolorat#2\endcsname{#1}% SAVE COLOR AT #2
  \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{#1}{#2}
  \textLabel{#1}{#2}{\themoveCounter}

  \stepMoveCounter
}

% ...

% Here's an example of what I mean by "flipping the colors":
\newcommand{\textLabel}[3]{%
  \setCoords{#2}%

  \draw (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
  node[
    color     = -\StoneColor{#2}, % A white stone should have a black text label, a black stone, a white text label
    inner sep = 1pt
  ] {#3};
}

Somehow the colors from the previous diagram are getting saved? I don't know how this thecolorat works exactly.
Anyways, I'm sorry for dumping such an obscenely long "MWE" (I've pasted a shorter MWE down below), but I think 95% of the code is ignorable, and I've tried to separate it into sections to make things easier — if you would like to fiddle with SGF files, I highly suggest the editor Sabaki, which is what I've been using —:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{catchfile}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Drawing Stones

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708876/64441).
\newcommand\notwhite{black}
\newcommand\notblack{white}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708893/64441).
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_alph:n {e}

  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordX}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_i:nn #1 }
  }
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordY}{ m }{
    \boardSize + 1 - ~\int_from_alph:e { \use_ii:nn #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\setCoords}[1]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX{#1} - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY{#1} - 1}
}

\newcounter{moveCounter}
\setcounter{moveCounter}{1}

\newcommand{\stepMoveCounter}{
  \stepcounter{moveCounter}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Drawing Stones and Moves

\newcommand{\drawStoneFromSgfCoords}[2]{%
  \setCoords{#2}

  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.1mm]
    (\x * \step, \y * \step)
    circle [radius = 0.2575cm];
}

\newcommand{\drawMoveFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \expandafter\xdef\csname thecolorat#2\endcsname{#1}% SAVE COLOR AT #2
  \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{#1}{#2}
  \textLabel{#1}{#2}{\themoveCounter}

  \stepMoveCounter
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Labels

\newcommand\StoneColor[1]{% COMPLEMENTARY COLOR OF REFERENCED STONE
  \ifcsname thecolorat#1\endcsname
    \csname thecolorat#1\endcsname
  \else
    white% COMPLEMENT OF DEFAULT LABEL COLOR WHEN NOT ATOP EXISTING STONE
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\textLabel}[3]{%
  \setCoords{#2}%

  \draw (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
  node[
    color     = -\StoneColor{#2},
    inner sep = 1pt
  ] {#3};
}

\newcommand{\triangleLabel}[2]{
  \setCoords{#2}

  \draw (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
    node[
      isosceles triangle,
      draw                          = #1,
      color                         = -\StoneColor{#2},
      fill                          = \StoneColor{#2},
      minimum height                = \step * 10,
      minimum width                 = \step * 10,
      line width                    = 0.5mm,
      rotate                        = 90,
      isosceles triangle apex angle = 60,
      inner sep                     = 0pt,
    ] {};
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% SGF Parser

% From [this answer by @StevenB.Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709014/64441).
\long\def\Firstof#1#2\endFirstof{#1}

\newcommand\thecolorofB{black}
\newcommand\thecolorofAB{black}
\newcommand\thecolorofW{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofAW{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofMA{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofCR{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofTR{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofSQ{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofLB{white}

\long\def\Keytypeof#1{\csname thekeytypeof#1\endcsname}

\newcommand\thekeytypeofB{M}  % black move
\newcommand\thekeytypeofAB{A} % added (edited) black stone
\newcommand\thekeytypeofW{M}  % white move
\newcommand\thekeytypeofAW{A} % added (edited) white stone
\newcommand\thekeytypeofMA{K} % cross (mark) label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofCR{C} % circle label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofTR{T} % triangle label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofSQ{S} % square label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofLB{L} % text label

\newcommand{\parseSgf}[1]{%
  \setsepchar{(||)/;/]/[/:}%
  \readlist*\Z{#1}%

  \foreachitem \Branch \in \Z[]{%
  \foreachitem \Group \in \Z[\Branchcnt]{%
    \foreachitem \Key \in \Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt]{%
     \if\relax\Key\relax% IF BLANK KEY & VALUE, SKIP
     \else
      \itemtomacro\Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt, \Keycnt, 1]\KeyName
      \if\relax\KeyName\relax% IF VALUE, BUT NO KEYNAME, USE RECENT KEYNAME
        \let\KeyName\MostRecentKeyname
      \else
        \xdef\MostRecentKeyname{\KeyName}%
      \fi
      \itemtomacro\Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt, \Keycnt, 2, 1]\KeyValue

      \edef\tmp{{\csname thecolorof\KeyName\endcsname}{\KeyValue}}%

      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName M
        \expandafter\drawMoveFromSgfCoords\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName A
        \expandafter\drawStoneFromSgfCoords\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName K
        \expandafter\crossLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName C
        \expandafter\circleLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName T
        \expandafter\triangleLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName S
        \expandafter\squareLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName L
        \expandafter\textLabel\tmp{\Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt, \Keycnt, 2, 2]} 
      \fi
     \fi
    }
  }%
  }%
}

% From [this question/answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726141/64441)
\newcommand\parseSgfFile[1]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\mysgf}{#1}{}%
  \parseSgf{\mysgf}% 
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Grid

\newcommand{\calculateStep}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{\boardDimension / (\boardSize - 1)} % chktex 1
}

% From [this answer by @UlrichDiez](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709341/64441).
\pgfkeys{%
  %---------------------------------------------------------
  /phili/goGrid/.cd, 
    %-------------------------------------------------------
    % Dimensions
    board dimension/.store in    = \boardDimension,
    board dimension              = 10cm,
    board size/.store in         = \boardSize,
    board size                   = 19,
    %-------------------------------------------------------
    % Outline
    outline line width/.store in = \boardOutlineWidth,
    outline line width           = 0.7mm,
  %---------------------------------------------------------
  /phili/goban/.search also={/phili/goGrid},
  /phili/goban/.cd,  
    %-------------------------------------------------------
    % Scale
    scale/.store in              = \scale,
    scale                        = 1,
    %-------------------------------------------------------
    % Partial Boards
    horizontal clip start/.store in = \horClipStart,
    horizontal clip start           = -1,
    horizontal clip end/.store in   = \horClipEnd, % This is more like the width?
    horizontal clip end             = -1,
    vertical clip start/.store in   = \verClipStart,
    vertical clip start             = -1,
    vertical clip end/.store in     = \verClipEnd, % This is more like the height?
    vertical clip end               = -1,
  %---------------------------------------------------------
}

% Parameters
%
% - `board dimension` (in cm)
% - `board size` (square)
% 
% Example: A 19x19 board with size 10cm x 10cm:
%
% ```tex
% \goGrid[board dimension    = 10,
%         board size         = 9,
%         scale              = 1,
%         outline line width = 0.5mm]
% ```
\newcommand{\goGrid}[1][]{
  \pgfkeys{/phili/goGrid/.cd, #1}

  \calculateStep

  \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid
    (\boardDimension, \boardDimension);
  
  \boardOutline{\boardDimension}

  \drawHoshis
}

% Reference: [Drawing a Non-Jagged Grid Outline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/709298/64441)
%
% Parameters
%
% 1: dimension (in cm)
% 
% Example: `\boardOutline{10}`
\newcommand{\boardOutline}[1]{
  \draw[step       = #1,
        line width = \boardOutlineWidth,
        line cap   = rect] 
    (0, 0) grid (#1, #1);
}

% Example: A 19x19 board with size 10cm x 10cm: `\drawHoshis`
\newcommand{\drawHoshis}{
  \tikzmath{
    \hoshiRadius = \step * 0.125;
    %
    \centerHoshi = ceil(\boardSize / 2);
    %
    int \hoshiDistance;
    if \boardSize<12 then {
      \hoshiDistance = 3;
    } else {
      \hoshiDistance = 4;
    };
    %
    \hoshiComplement = \boardSize - \hoshiDistance + 1;
  }

  \drawCenterHoshi
  \drawCornerHoshis
  \ifnum\boardSize>6\relax
    \drawCornerHoshis
  \fi
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\boardSize}}{
    \ifnum\boardSize>13\relax
      \drawSideHoshis
    \fi
  }{}
}

\newcommand{\drawCenterHoshi}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\centerHoshiCoord}{(\centerHoshi - 1) * \step}

  \filldraw (\centerHoshiCoord, \centerHoshiCoord)
    circle [radius=\hoshiRadius];
}

\newcommand{\drawCornerHoshis}{
  \def\cornerHoshisArray{%
    {\hoshiDistance, \hoshiDistance},%
    {\hoshiComplement, \hoshiDistance},%
    {\hoshiDistance, \hoshiComplement },%
    {\hoshiComplement, \hoshiComplement}%
  }

  \loopOverHoshis{\cornerHoshisArray}
}

\newcommand{\loopOverHoshis}[1]{
  \foreach \sloc in #1 {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hoshiCoordX}{\step * ({\sloc}[0] - 1)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hoshiCoordY}{\step * ({\sloc}[1] - 1)}

    \filldraw (\hoshiCoordX, \hoshiCoordY)
      circle [radius=\hoshiRadius];
  }
}

\newcommand{\drawSideHoshis}{
  \def\sideHoshisArray{%
    {\hoshiDistance, \centerHoshi},%
    {\centerHoshi, \hoshiComplement},%
    {\centerHoshi, \hoshiDistance},%
    {\hoshiComplement, \centerHoshi}%
  }    

  \loopOverHoshis{\sideHoshisArray}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Goban Env

\newcommand\partialBoardClipping{
  \ifthenelse{
    \equal{\horClipStart}{-1} \AND
    \equal{\horClipEnd}{-1} \AND
    \equal{\verClipStart}{-1} \AND
    \equal{\verClipEnd}{-1}
  }{}{
    \tikzmath{
      \horStart = (-1.5 + \horClipStart) * \step;
      \horEnd   = (\horClipEnd) * \step;
      \verStart = (-1.5 + \verClipStart) * \step;
      \verEnd   = (\verClipEnd) * \step;
    }

    \clip (\horStart, \verStart) rectangle 
          (\horEnd, \verEnd);
  }
}

\newenvironment{goban}[1][]{
  \pgfkeys{/phili/goban/.cd, #1}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = \scale,
                      transform shape]
    \calculateStep

    \partialBoardClipping

    \goGrid
}{
    \setcounter{moveCounter}{1}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand\customGoban[1]{
  \begin{goban}[board dimension       = 10,
                board size            = 19,
                scale                 = 1,
                outline line width    = 0.55mm,
                horizontal clip start = 13,
                horizontal clip end   = 19,
                vertical clip start   = 14,
                vertical clip end     = 19]
    % \parseSgfFile{sgf/captura/#1.sgf}
    \parseSgf{#1}
  \end{goban}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\def\sgfA{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-09-13]AB[qd][rc][oc][qb][pb]AW[qc][pc][oe]AE[pd]PL[W];W[pd];B[pe];W[od]TR[ob][qe][rb][rd])}

\def\sgfB{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-09-19]AB[qc][qb][ra]AW[pb][pc][qa];B[rb])}

\def\sgfC{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-09-19]AW[rb][qc][rd][sa]AB[ra][qb][pb][nc]AE[oc];B[sb]LB[rb:A])}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
  \customGoban{\sgfA}
  \customGoban{\sgfC}
  \customGoban{\sgfB}
  \customGoban{\sgfA}
  \customGoban{\sgfC}
\end{document}

And here's probably an actual MWE, a more minimal adapation of @StevenB.Segletes' code, with the same issue:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{listofitems}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Drawing Stones

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708876/64441).
\newcommand\notwhite{black}
\newcommand\notblack{white}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708893/64441).
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_alph:n {e}

  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordX}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_i:nn #1 }
  }
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordY}{ m }{
    \boardSize + 1 - ~\int_from_alph:e { \use_ii:nn #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\setCoords}[1]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX{#1} - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY{#1} - 1}
}

\newcommand{\drawStoneFromSgfCoords}[2]{%
  \setCoords{#2}

  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.1mm]
    (\x * \step, \y * \step)
    circle [radius = 0.2575cm];
}

\newcommand{\drawMoveFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \expandafter\xdef\csname thecolorat#2\endcsname{#1}% SAVE COLOR AT #2
  \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{#1}{#2}
  \textLabel{#1}{#2}{\themoveCounter}

  \stepMoveCounter
}

\newcounter{moveCounter}
\setcounter{moveCounter}{1}

\newcommand{\stepMoveCounter}{
  \stepcounter{moveCounter}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Labels

\newcommand\StoneColor[1]{% COMPLEMENTARY COLOR OF REFERENCED STONE
  \ifcsname thecolorat#1\endcsname
    \csname thecolorat#1\endcsname
  \else
    white% COMPLEMENT OF DEFAULT LABEL COLOR WHEN NOT ATOP EXISTING STONE
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\textLabel}[3]{%
  \setCoords{#2}%
  \draw (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
  node[
    color = -\StoneColor{#2},
    fill = \StoneColor{#2},
    inner sep=1pt
  ] {#3};
}

\newcommand{\crossLabel}[2]{
  \setCoords{#2}
  \draw (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
  node[
    color = -\StoneColor{#2},
    fill = \StoneColor{#2},
    inner sep=1pt
  ] {$\times$};
}

\newcommand{\triangleLabel}[2]{
  \setCoords{#2}
  \draw (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
    node[
      isosceles triangle,
      draw                          = #1,
      line width                    = 0.5mm,
      color                         = -\StoneColor{#2},
      fill                          = -\StoneColor{#2},
      minimum height                = \step * 10,
      minimum width                 = \step * 10,
      rotate                        = 90,
      isosceles triangle apex angle = 60,
      inner sep                     = 0pt,
    ] {};
}

\newcommand{\squareLabel}[2]{
  \setCoords{#2}

  \draw (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
    node[
      draw         = #1,
      line width   = 0.5mm,
      color        = -\StoneColor{#2},
      fill         = -\StoneColor{#2},
      minimum size = \step * 10,
      inner sep    = 0pt,
    ] {};
}

\newcommand{\circleLabel}[2]{
  \setCoords{#2}

  \draw[
    draw         = #1,
    line width   = 0.5mm,
    color        = -\StoneColor{#2},
    fill         = -\StoneColor{#2},
    inner sep    = 0pt,
  ] (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
    circle[radius = \step / 4];
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% SGF Parser

% From [this answer by @StevenB.Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709014/64441).
\long\def\Firstof#1#2\endFirstof{#1}

\newcommand\thecolorofB{black}
\newcommand\thecolorofAB{black}
\newcommand\thecolorofW{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofAW{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofMA{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofCR{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofTR{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofSQ{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofLB{white}

\long\def\Keytypeof#1{\csname thekeytypeof#1\endcsname}

\newcommand\thekeytypeofB{M}  % black move
\newcommand\thekeytypeofAB{A} % added (edited) black stone
\newcommand\thekeytypeofW{M}  % white move
\newcommand\thekeytypeofAW{A} % added (edited) white stone
\newcommand\thekeytypeofMA{K} % cross (mark) label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofCR{C} % circle label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofTR{T} % triangle label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofSQ{S} % square label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofLB{L} % text label

\newcommand{\parseSgf}[1]{%
  \setsepchar{(||)/;/]/[/:}%
  \readlist*\Z{#1}%

  \foreachitem \Branch \in \Z[]{%
  \foreachitem \Group \in \Z[\Branchcnt]{%
    \foreachitem \Key \in \Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt]{%
     \if\relax\Key\relax% IF BLANK KEY & VALUE, SKIP
     \else
      \itemtomacro\Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt, \Keycnt, 1]\KeyName
      \if\relax\KeyName\relax% IF VALUE, BUT NO KEYNAME, USE RECENT KEYNAME
        \let\KeyName\MostRecentKeyname
      \else
        \xdef\MostRecentKeyname{\KeyName}%
      \fi
      \itemtomacro\Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt, \Keycnt, 2, 1]\KeyValue

      \edef\tmp{{\csname thecolorof\KeyName\endcsname}{\KeyValue}}%

      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName M
        \expandafter\drawMoveFromSgfCoords\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName A
        \expandafter\drawStoneFromSgfCoords\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName K
        \expandafter\crossLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName C
        \expandafter\circleLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName T
        \expandafter\triangleLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName S
        \expandafter\squareLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName L
        \expandafter\textLabel\tmp{\Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt, \Keycnt, 2, 2]} 
      \fi
     \fi
    }
  }%
  }%
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% SGFs

\def\sgfA{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-09-13]AB[qd][rc][oc][qb][pb]AW[qc][pc][oe]AE[pd]PL[W];W[pd];B[pe];W[od]TR[ob][qe][rb][rd])}

\def\sgfB{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-09-19]AB[qc][qb][ra]AW[pb][pc][qa];B[rb])}

\def\sgfC{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-09-19]AW[rb][qc][rd][sa]AB[ra][qb][pb][nc]AE[oc];B[sb]LB[rb:A])}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Setup

\pgfmathsetmacro{\boardDimension}{10}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\boardSize}{19}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{\boardDimension / (\boardSize - 1)}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);
    \parseSgf{\sgfA}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \\
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);
    \parseSgf{\sgfB}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \\
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid (10, 10);
    \parseSgf{\sgfA}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit
As @Qrrbrbirlbel mentioned, this is probably happening because xdef defines a global, and so the next diagram would have to deal with what was defined earlier. He suggests trying out changing xdef to edef:
\expandafter\edef\csname thecolorat#2\endcsname{#1}% SAVE COLOR AT #2

I think that improves things, but I haven't been able to find the right combination of fill/draw colors for the triangle label for example:
draw  = #1,
color = -\StoneColor{#2},
fill  = \StoneColor{#2},



Maybe if I could force everything to be white after the drawing of a diagram, that could be a workaround.

The \xdef in the definition of \drawMoveFromSgfCoords defines the macro globally. So if it will be access in the next diagram without being reset, the value might still be accessed.

That makes sense! Is there a way to reset things?

I don't know. It's best to wait for Steven. I don't see why something needs to be \xdefed but that doesn't mean anything. Even if it's over half a year ago, I'm sure he'll be able to identify the problem much faster. I've looked at your old question: I would have parsed the SGF via PGFParser and either drawn the element directly or stored the state of the diagram to be drawn later. I'm sure it's too late to propose a different approach.

It's never too late hehe. But anyways Steven's solution has been working very well for me these days. I try to make my code decoupled, so I think that if the implementation of the drawing library changed, not that much outside would feel the difference. I didn't know about the PGFParser library, it could be a nice option for a v2 of the drawing library.

Ah, the color is saved so that the inverse can be accessed later when the labels are to be drawn. Whether that needs to be global can be tested by replacing the \xdef with \edef and seeing if and what breaks.

I've tried doing \edef, but I'm not sure if it's gonna work, I think that then I can't make the "draw-color-fill" combination make any sense anymore. I think that it would make more sense to still use xdef but then reset everything somehow after each diagram. Anyways, if it's still possible to make the labels "draw-color-fill" work...

@Qrrbrbirlbel I've added an edit with your suggestions.

It seems I was missing that I needed to also do the edef thing for the stones, not only for the moves! I'm gonna post an answer soon, once I test it out a little bit more.

As @Qrrbrbirlbel mentioned, and as I suspected, there was something being shared between the diagrams. That was due to using \xdef, which defines global variables. A simple way to fix that would be using \edef instead.
And the other problem was that drawing a move was using the drawing a stone macro, but the \xdef was inside the drawing of a move, so drawing stones wouldn't get registered.
In the end, this is the core of the solution:
\newcommand{\drawStoneFromSgfCoords}[2]{%
  % Moved this from the macro below to here:
  \expandafter\edef\csname thecolorat#2\endcsname{#1} % SAVE COLOR AT #2

  % ...
}

\newcommand{\drawMoveFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{#1}{#2}
  
  % ...
}

