Latin Modern with Variable Font Weight

I suppose this question probably has a ton of duplicates, but I've been Googling it and the results are mostly garbage, so I'm gonna risk repeating things here.

I'm using TikZ to draw Go (board game) diagrams, and, on VS Code's default PDF viewer, the numbers look like I expected:

But, on other PDF viewers, the white numbers on the Black stones look way thinner. I think it might be a visual problem with white-on-black things. For example, here's another diagram I rendered with GIMP:

It looks thinner than on VS Code's PDF viewer:

So I wanted to maybe either make both be a little bit thicker, or only the white-on-black labels.
Is there a Latin Modern font with variable font weights? Using \textbf is way too thick for me.
Here's the code I'm using in my project. The summarized version is this:
\fontfamily{lmr}

\draw (\xCoord, \yCoord) 
  node[
    color     = -\StoneColor{#2},
    font      = \fontsize{\fontSize}{9pt}\selectfont,
  ] {#3};

Here's a not so minimal MWE, which I've adapted from this other question, you can basically ignore 95% of it, the \textLabel macro is the only important part for this question:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{catchfile}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Drawing Stones

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708876/64441).
\newcommand\notwhite{black}
\newcommand\notblack{white}

% From [this answer by @DavidCarlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708893/64441).
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_alph:n {e}

  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordX}{ m }{
    \int_from_alph:e { \use_i:nn #1 }
  }
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringToCoordY}{ m }{
    \boardSize + 1 - ~\int_from_alph:e { \use_ii:nn #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\setCoords}[1]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\stringToCoordX{#1} - 1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\stringToCoordY{#1} - 1}
}

\newcounter{moveCounter}
\setcounter{moveCounter}{1}

\newcommand{\stepMoveCounter}{
  \stepcounter{moveCounter}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Drawing Stones and Moves

\newcommand{\drawStoneFromSgfCoords}[2]{%
  \setCoords{#2}

  \draw[draw = \UseName{not#1}, fill = #1, line width = 0.2mm]
    (\x * \step, \y * \step)
    circle [radius = 0.2575cm];
}

\newcommand{\drawMoveFromSgfCoords}[2]{
  \expandafter\xdef\csname thecolorat#2\endcsname{#1}% SAVE COLOR AT #2
  \drawStoneFromSgfCoords{#1}{#2}
  \textLabel{#1}{#2}{\themoveCounter}

  \stepMoveCounter
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Labels

\newcommand\StoneColor[1]{% COMPLEMENTARY COLOR OF REFERENCED STONE
  \ifcsname thecolorat#1\endcsname
    \csname thecolorat#1\endcsname
  \else
    white% COMPLEMENT OF DEFAULT LABEL COLOR WHEN NOT ATOP EXISTING STONE
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\textLabel}[3]{%
  \setCoords{#2}%

  \fontfamily{lmr}

  \draw (\x * \step, \y * \step) 
  node[
    color     = -\StoneColor{#2},
  ] {#3};
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% SGF Parser

% From [this answer by @StevenB.Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709014/64441).
\long\def\Firstof#1#2\endFirstof{#1}

\newcommand\thecolorofB{black}
\newcommand\thecolorofAB{black}
\newcommand\thecolorofW{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofAW{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofMA{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofCR{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofTR{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofSQ{white}
\newcommand\thecolorofLB{white}

\long\def\Keytypeof#1{\csname thekeytypeof#1\endcsname}

\newcommand\thekeytypeofB{M}  % black move
\newcommand\thekeytypeofAB{A} % added (edited) black stone
\newcommand\thekeytypeofW{M}  % white move
\newcommand\thekeytypeofAW{A} % added (edited) white stone
\newcommand\thekeytypeofMA{K} % cross (mark) label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofCR{C} % circle label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofTR{T} % triangle label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofSQ{S} % square label
\newcommand\thekeytypeofLB{L} % text label

\newcommand{\parseSgf}[1]{%
  \setsepchar{(||)/;/]/[/:}%
  \readlist*\Z{#1}%

  \foreachitem \Branch \in \Z[]{%
  \foreachitem \Group \in \Z[\Branchcnt]{%
    \foreachitem \Key \in \Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt]{%
     \if\relax\Key\relax% IF BLANK KEY & VALUE, SKIP
     \else
      \itemtomacro\Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt, \Keycnt, 1]\KeyName
      \if\relax\KeyName\relax% IF VALUE, BUT NO KEYNAME, USE RECENT KEYNAME
        \let\KeyName\MostRecentKeyname
      \else
        \xdef\MostRecentKeyname{\KeyName}%
      \fi
      \itemtomacro\Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt, \Keycnt, 2, 1]\KeyValue

      \edef\tmp{{\csname thecolorof\KeyName\endcsname}{\KeyValue}}%

      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName M
        \expandafter\drawMoveFromSgfCoords\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName A
        \expandafter\drawStoneFromSgfCoords\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName K
        \expandafter\crossLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName C
        \expandafter\circleLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName T
        \expandafter\triangleLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName S
        \expandafter\squareLabel\tmp
      \fi
      \if\Keytypeof\KeyName L
        \expandafter\textLabel\tmp{\Z[\Branchcnt, \Groupcnt, \Keycnt, 2, 2]} 
      \fi
     \fi
    }
  }%
  }%
}

% From [this question/answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726141/64441)
\newcommand\parseSgfFile[1]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\mysgf}{#1}{}%
  \parseSgf{\mysgf}% 
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Grid

\newcommand{\calculateStep}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\step}{\boardDimension / (\boardSize - 1)} % chktex 1
}

% From [this answer by @UlrichDiez](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709341/64441).
\pgfkeys{%
  %---------------------------------------------------------
  /phili/goGrid/.cd, 
    %-------------------------------------------------------
    % Dimensions
    board dimension/.store in    = \boardDimension,
    board dimension              = 10cm,
    board size/.store in         = \boardSize,
    board size                   = 19,
    %-------------------------------------------------------
    % Outline
    outline line width/.store in = \boardOutlineWidth,
    outline line width           = 0.7mm,
  %---------------------------------------------------------
  /phili/goban/.search also={/phili/goGrid},
  /phili/goban/.cd,  
    %-------------------------------------------------------
    % Scale
    scale/.store in              = \scale,
    scale                        = 1,
    %-------------------------------------------------------
    % Partial Boards
    horizontal clip start/.store in = \horClipStart,
    horizontal clip start           = -1,
    horizontal clip end/.store in   = \horClipEnd, % This is more like the width?
    horizontal clip end             = -1,
    vertical clip start/.store in   = \verClipStart,
    vertical clip start             = -1,
    vertical clip end/.store in     = \verClipEnd, % This is more like the height?
    vertical clip end               = -1,
  %---------------------------------------------------------
}

% Parameters
%
% - `board dimension` (in cm)
% - `board size` (square)
% 
% Example: A 19x19 board with size 10cm x 10cm:
%
% ```tex
% \goGrid[board dimension    = 10,
%         board size         = 9,
%         scale              = 1,
%         outline line width = 0.5mm]
% ```
\newcommand{\goGrid}[1][]{
  \pgfkeys{/phili/goGrid/.cd, #1}

  \calculateStep

  \draw[step=\step] (0, 0) grid
    (\boardDimension, \boardDimension);
  
  \boardOutline{\boardDimension}

  \drawHoshis
}

% Reference: [Drawing a Non-Jagged Grid Outline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/709298/64441)
%
% Parameters
%
% 1: dimension (in cm)
% 
% Example: `\boardOutline{10}`
\newcommand{\boardOutline}[1]{
  \draw[step       = #1,
        line width = \boardOutlineWidth,
        line cap   = rect] 
    (0, 0) grid (#1, #1);
}

% Example: A 19x19 board with size 10cm x 10cm: `\drawHoshis`
\newcommand{\drawHoshis}{
  \tikzmath{
    \hoshiRadius = \step * 0.125;
    %
    \centerHoshi = ceil(\boardSize / 2);
    %
    int \hoshiDistance;
    if \boardSize<12 then {
      \hoshiDistance = 3;
    } else {
      \hoshiDistance = 4;
    };
    %
    \hoshiComplement = \boardSize - \hoshiDistance + 1;
  }

  \drawCenterHoshi
  \drawCornerHoshis
  \ifnum\boardSize>6\relax
    \drawCornerHoshis
  \fi
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\boardSize}}{
    \ifnum\boardSize>13\relax
      \drawSideHoshis
    \fi
  }{}
}

\newcommand{\drawCenterHoshi}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\centerHoshiCoord}{(\centerHoshi - 1) * \step}

  \filldraw (\centerHoshiCoord, \centerHoshiCoord)
    circle [radius=\hoshiRadius];
}

\newcommand{\drawCornerHoshis}{
  \def\cornerHoshisArray{%
    {\hoshiDistance, \hoshiDistance},%
    {\hoshiComplement, \hoshiDistance},%
    {\hoshiDistance, \hoshiComplement },%
    {\hoshiComplement, \hoshiComplement}%
  }

  \loopOverHoshis{\cornerHoshisArray}
}

\newcommand{\loopOverHoshis}[1]{
  \foreach \sloc in #1 {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hoshiCoordX}{\step * ({\sloc}[0] - 1)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\hoshiCoordY}{\step * ({\sloc}[1] - 1)}

    \filldraw (\hoshiCoordX, \hoshiCoordY)
      circle [radius=\hoshiRadius];
  }
}

\newcommand{\drawSideHoshis}{
  \def\sideHoshisArray{%
    {\hoshiDistance, \centerHoshi},%
    {\centerHoshi, \hoshiComplement},%
    {\centerHoshi, \hoshiDistance},%
    {\hoshiComplement, \centerHoshi}%
  }    

  \loopOverHoshis{\sideHoshisArray}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Goban Env

\newcommand\partialBoardClipping{
  \ifthenelse{
    \equal{\horClipStart}{-1} \AND
    \equal{\horClipEnd}{-1} \AND
    \equal{\verClipStart}{-1} \AND
    \equal{\verClipEnd}{-1}
  }{}{
    \tikzmath{
      \horStart = (-1.5 + \horClipStart) * \step;
      \horEnd   = (\horClipEnd) * \step;
      \verStart = (-1.5 + \verClipStart) * \step;
      \verEnd   = (\verClipEnd) * \step;
    }

    \clip (\horStart, \verStart) rectangle 
          (\horEnd, \verEnd);
  }
}

\newenvironment{goban}[1][]{
  \pgfkeys{/phili/goban/.cd, #1}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = \scale,
                      transform shape]
    \calculateStep

    \partialBoardClipping

    \goGrid
}{
    \setcounter{moveCounter}{1}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand\customGoban[1]{
  \begin{goban}[board dimension       = 10,
                board size            = 19,
                scale                 = 1,
                outline line width    = 0.55mm,
                horizontal clip start = 11,
                horizontal clip end   = 19,
                vertical clip start   = 9,
                vertical clip end     = 19]
    % \parseSgfFile{sgf/captura/#1.sgf}
    \parseSgf{#1}
  \end{goban}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\def\sgfA{(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2024-10-15]PL[B]AE[pe][qe][pc][oc][qd][od];B[qd];W[od];B[oc];W[pd];B[pc];W[qe];B[nd];W[qc];B[rd];W[qb];B[re];W[qf];B[pb];W[nc];B[nb];W[mc];B[ne];W[of];B[mb];W[lc];B[lb];W[pa];B[ob];W[rc];B[rf];W[qg];B[rg];W[rh];B[qh];W[ri];B[qi];W[qj])}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
  \customGoban{\sgfA}
\end{document}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I'll try creating an MWE later, but I think it's probably not necessary for this question, since just having a variable font weight version of LM is probably enough.

there are other ways which one can use to make a font appear bolder, not just variable fonts.

questions shouldn't depend on external links so they remain useful to future readers. anybody who wants to help has to complete your code somehow. it isn't clear which fonts you are using here or how this is being compiled.

lmr has other weights than standard and bold, by the way, even if not variable ones.

@cfr What other weights are available? I only know of \textmd and \textbf.

Even though I still think it wasn't very necessary, I've just added an MWE.

there's also a semi-bold. \fontfamily{clm}\fontseries{sb}\selectfont (for example).

Try to use NewCM family. It provides classical weight of Computer Modern (aka Latin Modern) and Book variant too. The Book variant is little thicker.

@cfr For me, it's saying LaTeX Font: Font shape 'TU/clm/sb/n' undefined (Font) using 'TU/lmr/m/n' instead.

@wipet Thanks for the suggestion! I like NewCM's thickness much more. The only thing I find weird is that the number is a bit taller than the number 2, and when it's thicker, it's even more pronounced, super weird, regular CM does that too. Anyways, how do you properly configure it? I've been using this: \usepackage[default]{fontsetup} \newfontfamily\ncm{NewCM10-Book.otf}, which is more or less mentioned in their docs, but when I compile my book as a whole, some chapters say the font shape is undefined.

This is the specific message I get: LaTeX Font: Font shape 'TU/NewCMMath-Book.otf(3)/b/n' undefined (Font) using 'TU/NewCMMath-Book.otf(3)/m/n' instead.

@wipet I thought the NewCM family was going to be enough, but it turned out to be too thin on print. So I've reasked this question on r/fonts.
